# Ubuntu web Server and file storage

Tags: web-server, ftp, ubuntu-16.04

As stated,

- If I have an Ubuntu desktop and have a web server within it, can I make another file server to store the database, files etc? or I just need to stick with the computer I installed the web server?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. You can either have webserver, database and file storage server in a same server or in separate servers.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I can access another computer web server? Currently I am using hosts file point to 127.0.0.1 to get access to another computer's web server site. Is it an appropriate method? Any other method I can do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point.

Comment: I meant now I have a computer where web server installed and have a site running localhost. And I tried and success open the site on another computer by modified the host file and point to that localhost site. Is it an appropriate method?

Comment: How do you access from the other computer to your webserver? What do you exactly type as URL?

Comment: Oh. Okay I changed the host file on another compiter by afding code 127.0.0.1 localsiteaddress. Then would be okay to access the site from the web server. If you jave antivirus software just ask it to unblock the port.

Comment: From another computer I meant

Comment: Why don't you access to your webserver by writing its IP address?

Comment: Erm will try. Maybe its easier?

Comment: Oh Ic coz I have multiple sites set up.

Comment: Create a new question providing as much information as possible about your environment and ask clearly what is your requirement/doubt so that other people can help you.